# Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2012 Power Tools DB Backup Tool Error

Tags: tfs, backup

I have upgraded our TFS 2010 (Win 2008 R2 SP1, SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1, WSS 3.0 SP2) to TFS 2012 (Win 2012 RTM, SQL Server 2012, SPF 2010 SP1). This is a single server farm (TFS, SP are installed on the same server). TFS build is installed on a separate server. Everything works fine.

In the TFS 2010 environment, I was able to use the TFS 2010 Power Tool to create a backup plan. I installed/upgraded the TFS power tool to [TFS 2012 Power Tool.](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b1ef7eb2-e084-4cb8-9bc7-06c3bad9148f). When I try to create a backup plan using the backup plan wizard, I get errors. (my guess is during the upgrade some permission to the DB was revoked.)

This is my backup plan settings:

[image]

[image]

It looks like there are three issues:

**1. Cannot find reporting databases**

```
The following is logged:

[Info   @22:38:23.430] +-+-+-+-+-| Running VerifyReportingDatabases: Verify valid SQL Reporting Services database connection string |+-+-+-+-+-

[Info   @22:38:23.446] 

[Info   @22:38:23.446] +-+-+-+-+-| Verify valid SQL Reporting Services database connection string |+-+-+-+-+-

[Info   @22:38:23.446] Starting Node: DataBaseAccess

[Info   @22:38:23.446] NodePath : Container/Progress/DataBaseAccess

[Info   @22:38:23.524] Node returned: Error

[Error  @22:38:23.524] Cannot find reporting databases

[Info   @22:38:23.524] Completed VerifyReportingDatabases: Error

[Info   @22:38:23.524] -----------------------------------------------------
```

**2. Cannot find SharePoint databases for applications.**

> [Info   @22:38:23.540] +-+-+-+-+-| Running VerifySharepointDatabases:
>   Verify valid SharePoint database connection string |+-+-+-+-+-
>
> ```
> [Info   @22:38:23.540] 
>
> [Info   @22:38:23.540] +-+-+-+-+-| Verify valid SharePoint database connection string |+-+-+-+-+-
>
> [Info   @22:38:23.540] Starting Node: DataBaseAccess
>
> [Info   @22:38:23.540] NodePath : Container/Progress/Conditional/DataBaseAccess
>
> [Info   @22:38:26.965] Node returned: Error
>
> [Error  @22:38:26.965] Cannot find SharePoint databases for applications:  http://xxxxxx-tfs01:17012/. This tool does not support multiple SharePoint farms in TFS configuration. If your TFS server is using multiple farms for SharePoint application, please exclude SharePoint component from the backup plan
>
> [Info   @22:38:26.965] Completed VerifySharepointDatabases: Error
>
> [Info   @22:38:26.965] -----------------------------------------------------
>
>
> [Info   @22:38:26.965] +-+-+-+-+-| Running VerifyBackupEncryptionKeyOperation: Verify > Reporting Services encryption key can be backed up |+-+-+-+-+-
>
> [Info   @22:38:26.965] 
>
> [Info   @22:38:26.965] +-+-+-+-+-| Verify Reporting Services encryption key can be backed up |+-+-+-+-+-
>
> [Info   @22:38:26.965] Starting Node: VerifyBackupEncryptionKeyOperation
>
> [Info   @22:38:26.965] NodePath : Container/Progress/Conditional/VerifyBackupEncryptionKeyOperation
>
> [Info   @22:38:27.059] Node returned: Error [Error  @22:38:27.059] Provider load failure 
>
> [Info   @22:38:27.059] Completed VerifyBackupEncryptionKeyOperation: Error
>
> [Info   @22:38:27.059] -----------------------------------------------------
> ```

**3. Alert setup fails**

> [Info   @22:43:57.295] +-+-+-+-+-| Running VerifyEmailNotifications:
>   Verify Email Notifications |+-+-+-+-+-
>
> ```
> [Info   @22:43:57.295] 
>
> [Info   @22:43:57.295] +-+-+-+-+-| Verify Email Notifications |+-+-+-+-+-
>
> [Info   @22:43:57.295] Starting Node: VerifyEmailNotifications
>
> [Info   @22:43:57.295] NodePath : Container/Conditional/Progress/VerifyEmailNotifications
>
> [Info   @22:44:05.461] Node returned: Error [Error  @22:44:05.461] The Backup Task account 'xxxxxxx-TFS01\TFSServiceAccount' either does not have permissions on your SMTP host or the password specified is invalid. Select an account with permissions to send emails and confirm the password is correct.
>
> [Info   @22:44:05.461] Completed VerifyEmailNotifications: Error
>
> [Info   @22:44:05.461] -----------------------------------------------------
> ```

This was working in the TFS 2010 environment.
  [image]

Comment: If I disable the report & sharepoint DB & Alerts (since these cause errors in my situation; and I really do not want to disable these backups.), I am able to create the backup plan successfully. But, in the main window of the Database Backup Tools, under Scheduled Tasks Information, there is no entry. It is blank. If I go to Windows task scheduler, I do see an entry there for TfsTransactionBackup (at 12:00 AM every day...).

Comment: You can follow up this issue on the MS forum as well: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfspowertools/thread/4fef9e40-8330-4a64-865e-b96dab66522c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use the TFS 2012 Backup Power Tools.

Instead use SQL Server Maintenance Plan for TFS DBs backup and PowerShell cmdlets for SP farm backup.

The following MSDN [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh561429.aspx) provides a step-by-step on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use the [the article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh561429.aspx) you mentioned for TFS2010.  When I saw the TFSBackup.exe/TFSRestore in the tools folder I thought they had gotten the Backup Plan Wizard correct. I can't get the wizard to work either.  Luckily, I can take the code I made for TFS2010.  It isn't straight forward.  Very disappointed this basic function of back up and restore still doesn't work well.